# Vue.js event to fire after data is updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js app of which I have a couple of components for, just to handle some repetitive tasks.

I'm also fetching data from an AJAX request.

What I'd like some input on is if there is an event that fires after Vue data (`treeData` and `flatTreeData`) has been updated and actioned so I can perform any additional actions?

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
        treeData: {items: {}},
        flatTreeData: [],
    },
});

$.getJSON('./paths.json').done(function(data) {

    // apply the file structure to the vue app
    demo.treeData = data;

    demo.flatTreeData = flattenTree(data);

});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `watch` property of the Vue instance to add listeners to variable changes: http://vuejs.org/api/#watch

```
watch: {
    'treeData': function (val, oldVal) {
      console.log('new: %s, old: %s', val, oldVal)
    }
}
```

If you are going to be `watch`ing an object like `treeData`, you may need to use the `deep` flag to watch the entire object tree.

```
watch: {
    'treeData':  {
        handler:function (val, oldVal){
            console.log('new: %s, old: %s', val, oldVal)
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd use a `computed` property here instead.

You can do:

```
{
  data: {
    treeData: {}
  },
  computed: {
    flatTreeData: function () {
      return flattenTree(this.treeData);
    }
  }
}
```

Now this way every time you update `treeData`, `flatTreeData` also gets updated.

Comment: This seems like the more vue-esque solution.

Comment: +1, this is the best option for `flatTreeData`.  A `watch` function on `treeData` and a computed property for `flatTreeData` will do nicely.

Comment: Yeah, both will work in this situation for sure, just think the computed property is more clear.

Comment: Yes but he will still need the watch function to fire off any other events he wants.  Computed property will only work for `flatTreeData` so it doesn't take care of his question.

Comment: I see what you're saying now that I'm reading a bit closer. I was just looking at the code.

Comment: Thanks @BillCriswell, I do need a way to handle some other events, however this is still helpful as computed properties will improve my code.